# Check the type of a generic lambda parameter

Tags: c++, lambda

I have a generic lambda function that is called with several unrelated structs as its parameter.
Inside, I want to execute some code only if the parameter is of a special type.

```
auto const my_lambda = [](auto obj) {
    // do something with obj
    if (decltype(obj) == SpecialType) // <-- pseudo code, does not work
         auto x = obj.specialMember; // Access to a special member that is present in SpecialType, but not the other types this lambda is called with
}
```

Comment: There's no difference in this case between an auto lambda and a function template. The dupe target doesn't actually seem to have an answer with `if constexpr`, so you could add an answer there.

Comment: I can understand the duplicate reference. But lambdas are easier than function templates and cannot have template parameters. For me personally it was not that straightforward to combine the several individual pieces, so I think it is benefical to have everything in one place. That's the reason why I posted this.

Comment: No, lambdas can absolutely have template parameters (that's what `auto` is in the function argument). It's just that you can't *name* those parameters until c++20.

Comment: Well, they don't have named template arguments is what I meant to say. My point still stands that you need to retrieve the type with decltype and decay_t, since you cannot name the template parameter. This is not mentioned in the other question and was the main problem that I had to overcome here.

Comment: Ok, I guess the dupe is not entirely appropriate, so I'll retract it.

Comment: Thanks :) I hope I was not too defensive about my post. It was simply the first time I decided to share my findings with the public to help others and was a bit disappointed when it was closed within seconds ;)

Comment: I am sorry about closing it so soon. I know from experience that this can be very discouraging, and I hope that this doesn't put you off from trying again. There's nothing wrong with the question, or the answer below, it's just that it's possibly a question that's been asked and answered before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach with `decltype` already goes into the right direction.
Two types can be compared with `std::is_same_v<Type1, Type2>`
To prevent the compiler from complaining about the undefined `.specialMember` for the other calls, `if constexpr` is needed.

This amounts to:

```
auto const my_lambda = [](auto obj) {
    // do something with obj
    if constexpr (std::is_same_v<decltype(obj), SpecialType>)
         auto x = obj.specialMember; // Access to a special member that is present in SpecialType, but not the other types this lambda is called with
}
```

If the parameter is passed as a reference, an additional `std::decay_t` is needed to strip the parameter type from any `const&` and the like.

```
auto const my_lambda = [](auto const& obj) {
    // do something with obj
    if constexpr (std::is_same_v<std::decay_t<decltype(obj)>, SpecialType>)
         auto x = obj.specialMember; // Access to a special member that is present in SpecialType, but not the other types this lambda is called with
}
```

Comment: You don't need `std::decay_t` since `auto obj` normally can't become a reference. The only way it can become a reference is if the template arguments are specified explicitly: `my_lambda.operator()<int &>(foo);`.

Comment: Ah that's good to know. But you would still need it in case of `auto my_lambda = [](auto const& obj)`, right? I'll update the answer accordingly.

Comment: Yep, in this case you need it.